# On click open popup with form and then on submit download and close it! How?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, popup

Here is what I am trying to do

1. Click on download link.
2. On click Popup will open. Contact form is in the popup.
3. On submit button send mail and auto start download of PDF file.
4. At the same time of starting of download close the popup without redirecting to any page.

I tried using `.click()` `window.open()`

```
$('#theForm').submit(function(){

            event.preventDefault();

            var $form = $( this ),

            url = $form.attr( 'action' );

            var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

            /* Alerts the results */

            posting.done(function( data ) {

                $(".modal-backdrop.fade.in").css("display", "none");

                document.getElementById("anchorID").click();

                $("#pdfdownload").css("display", "none");


            });

});
```

I am able to open download link using this code but browser blocks it as a popup. Please help me to find the solution.

Thank You

Comment: I also encountered this issue, the solution I did was to enable the popup for my site. You can find that on the browser settings.

Comment: @reignsly But that doesn't enable popup for other people and their browser, hopefully you're not the only user of your site

Comment: @MarkoMackic yeah your right. So I just instruct my users to enable them. I tried using the modal windows but it will create a separate window what i want is to open a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers block popup windows because they are typically annoying and employed by malicious advertisements.

The better way to go about this is to use a [modal window](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window), which is basically the same as a popup, but instead of being a separate browser window, it's simply a separate element within the page that hovers above other content.

Comment: I will try to do that. Do you have link of any easy tutorial about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Use bootstrap modal:**

```
<script>
function send(){
var  name = $("input#name").val();
var  email = $("input#email").val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send.php", //your mailing code is place on send.php
        data:'name='+ name'&email='+email,
        success: function(data){
        $('#download').modal('hide');
        window.location.href='uploads/yourpdf.pdf'; //your file location        
            });
        }
}
</script>
```

The html code

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download">Download</a>

<!-- modal for download and contact -->
<div class="modal fade" id="download" role="dialog" >
<div class="modal-dialog" >
<div class="modal-content">
<!-- Your contact form goes here --->
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email">
<button onclick="send();">send</button>
</form>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: I tried this but its redirecting me to `action=` url. I block this using `event.preventDefault()`. But now download link is opening in same window. I want to open it in new tab or window.

Comment: ` window.open('uploads/yourpdf.pdf');` it will open in new tab